# i want to compress the file by the deflater but it seems doesn't work

Tags: java

i have to do some **precompress** before the file upload, and i want to use the **deflaterOutputStream** to compress the file but ***it doesn't work***, if i have a file about 10MB when i compress it on the outputstream it still 10MB, and i don't know why, and i also want to know that how to ***exchange the outputstream to a file*** with **this method** that compare the OutputStream size with the fileSize to judge the whether it compress or not.  Thanks a lot.

```
public class test {
    public static int m_lvl;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Path file = new File("a.jpg").toPath();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream((int) new File("a.png").toPath().toFile().length());
            OutputStream bo = new DeflaterOutputStream( bos, new Deflater( m_lvl, true), 512 );
            Files.copy(file, bos);
            System.out.println((int) new File("a.zip").toPath().toFile().length());
            System.out.println(bos.size());

            bo.close();
            bos.close();
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `DeflaterOutputStream` is just  a zip format. You can't zip a zip file any further.

Comment: @JohnGiotta  is there any way to compress the file ?

Comment: Zip files are already compressed with the same algorithm Deflater uses.

Comment: **thank you** .but i already compress the img or mp3 but it still doesn't work in such method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the question it looks like you are trying to compress any file.

There are a few concepts which you should try to understand and have nothing to do with Java itself, but with data compression and reconstruction.

There are at two types (as my limited knowledge knows :)) of algorithms for data compression/decompression:

1. [Lossless algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression), for example: [ZIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format))
2. [Lossy algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression), for example [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)

Without entering into much detail, what you want to do is pick some *Raw Data*, compress it (so it occupies less space) and send it over to someone.

From the list of algorithms above, you may pick one or the other depending on your needs. For example, you will perhaps pick a Lossless algorithm if you require that no information is lost when the data is compress (imagine a .docx file or any other document such as the binary information of a computer program).

Otherwise, you might pick a lossy algorithm if, for example, you're displaying an image to another human user and don't mind some information being lost because the human eye can't see it all.

Now, the problem resides in the fact that what you're now trying to do is compress an already compressed file.

Imagine the following:

1. You have a text file filled with 64kb of the letter "a" or "a" repeated 64kb times (using 64kb of disk space).
2. When you want to compress it using a lossless algorithm you might get a compressed file with something "65536a" in a single line using perhaps 6bytes of disk space, meaning a repeated 64kb times in the original file.
3. Imagine that for some reason you don't need to know how many times a is repeated - lossy compression, and you use a lossy algorithm to do that and get a single file with a line which reads "a" using perhaps 1 byte of disk space, meaning a appears in the original file.
4. Now, if for some reason you want a lossless compressed file of the lossy compressed file, using my reasoning, you might get something like "1a" which now occupies 2 bytes of disk space, ence it is a bigger file.

That is basically what you're trying to do. Compress an already compressed file, and, depending on the algorithm in question, you might get a smaller file or not. Most probably, when compressing from lossy to lossless you might get a bigger file as in my example.

**As I have tried to resume. Compression depends when whether or not you have redundant information to be expressed in shorter ways.**

**EDIT 2**: Refactoring the response in order to clarify a little bit more.
**EDIT 3**: Found out a type on my listing of algorithms

Comment: but when i compress a *.mp3 or *.jpg it still doesn't work.I'm really confused!

Comment: @JasonLong you should use MP3 or JPG in your question as example. A zip files is bad example.

Comment: @JasonLong MP3s and JPGs are also compressed formats and also won't compress much further.

Comment: @JasonLong A zip file uses a lossless compression algorithm... In short words, when you try to compress an already compressed file (with the same algorithm), while you won't be able to compress it any further, you might even get a bigger file. That is why I linked you to the wikipedia page. You might also want to try and zip out a .jpg file and see what happens.

Comment: @JoãoRebelo when i compress a jpg , it get a bigger one really .And on other word , the deflater just compress the string ? Or it just incident that i meet a file that already compressed? thanks for your patient!

Comment: @JoãoRebelo i know what your purpose ! Whether a file can be compress depends on whether the file has extra data can compress or not. If there nothing more it file after compress without any variety! it that right?

Comment: @Jason Long I will update my answer, but short answer is that compression works on repeated information that can be described/written in shorter means. When you have that requisite you will effectively compress something. Otherwise, you will not! Tell me if I made that clear.

Comment: @JasonLong see my updated answer... I hope it helps. If not, please let me know so I can make it better :)

Comment: @JoãoRebelo It is really explict! Thanks for your help!